# Where is the right place to close a server socket (Python)

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server program that can maintain connection with multiple clients. I want to be able to close the socket in response to the message CLOSE by client, or for some other reason. The problem is that the server is stuck on the accept() method and does not care if I close the socket in some other place.

I can use some flag in the main server while, and close the socket after this while, however that means I will have to connect to the server myself after the client request, in order for the while condition to be checked, which smells like really terrible programming.

The code:

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 9992 # Arbitrary non-privileged port


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\r\n') #send only takes string
    data=''
    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data += conn.recv(1024)
        print data
        if data == 'CLOSE':
            global s
            conn.sendall('You have requested to destroy the connection...')
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            return
        if data.find('\n') != -1:
            conn.sendall('OK...' + data + '\r\n')
            data=''






#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    try:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

        #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
        start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))
    except:
        print 'socket issue sorry'
        break
```

Comment: Your question is not clear and neither are your comments:)  When a client sends the 'CLOSE' message, do you want the server to disconnect that client only or shut down the entire server, ie. disconnct all clients and exit?

Comment: I want to disconnect all the clients and not wait for more incoming connections. I want to get out of the accept() wait.